# How can I input space separated integers in pyhton numpy array. (Like the list(map(int,input().spli(" ")) function does for a list.)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, input

I have tried to find alternatives but only available for list not for numpy arrays

I tried this but didnt work:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 204, in ones
a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer
```

I need a version of `list(map(int,input().split(" "))` for numpy arrays.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to get `shape` from `input()` (you don't show any code).  `shape` is supposed to be list or tuple,  So you list conversion is still relevant.  The `np.array(alist)` function also takes a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert to a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np

numbers = input('Enter some numbers: ').split()
x = np.array(list(map(int, numbers)))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Enter some numbers: 1 2 3 4 5
[1 2 3 4 5]
```